# Do actors use prosthetics in naked scene of non-porn movies? And why?

Tags: effects

Watching (non-pornographic) movies that contains nudity, I noticed that sometimes the genitals of the actors or actresses look fake. For example, in [The Master (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1560747/) there's a scene with many naked women, and it seems to me that their privates are actually covered by some [merkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkin). Similarly, in other movies I noticed naked actors with what I believed to be the "male version" of merkin, although now I can't remember which specific movies.

Is it true that nudity is sometime faked using this prosthetic? And why?

My guess is that it is done to circumvent some rating rules, like the directors/producers want a scene with nudity but they don't want the movie being rated for nudity and so they cover the actors/actresses' genitals with prosthetics.

Comment: This is entriely at the discretion of the actor. "Fake" privates would still be subject to the same censorship rules as real ones.

Comment: This is rather broad. Sometimes is the answer. Return of the Living Dead (1985) used a prosthetic to cover Trash's vagina, for example. Many movies do not.

Comment: I recall *Deadpool* (2016) actually did the opposite and CGI'd a penis onto Ryan Reynolds during the fight against Ajax in the burning Weapon X facility, because without it, it just looked odd.

Comment: @Paulie_D source?

Comment: @MeatTrademark I'm not asking if ALL movies do that, but if some movies do that and why. You said that Return of the Living Dead did it, so that's almost an answer to my questions.

Comment: The obvious reason is that the actor doesn't want to be naked, or depending on the scene, to have sex with their co-star.

Comment: Reading the wikipedia article you linked, pretty much answers the question.

Comment: Specific info from 2 I’ve worked on … Look of Love merkins on *strippers*. Hair wasn’t trimmed in the 60s. Relik no prosthetics (except obvious facial *injuries*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOMETIMES**

[Return of the Living Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_Living_Dead) (1985) used a prosthetic on Trash's ([Linnea Quigley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnea_Quigley)) vagina to make it smooth. This was to avoid being unrated because she was naked and dancing in a sexually suggestive way in a cemetery. (The film also has some extreme gore effects, so graphic full-frontal nudity didn't help.)

Sadly, I cannot link to the RotLD commentary or the documentary "[MORE BRAINS!](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2011972/)" One or both of these confirm this.

That is one example. Many movies have straight-up nudity.

Comment: to add to this https://www.marieclaire.com/celebrity/g18208404/biggest-celebrity-prosthetic-penises-fake-bulges-in-movies-tv/